# При authentication mode=forms не проходит быстрая регистрация через post запрос

Tags: post, mvc, аутентификация

Проект c# mvc asp net, authentication mode=forms. Есть обычная регистрация, с вводом пароля и логина. Делаю быструю регистрацию по уже существующей в другом приложении чернз post. Сама регистрация проходит успешно, а authentication нет. При post почему-то authentication mode=''.
Я совсем немного в этой области, поэтому вопросы: 1. Можно ли authentication mode при post как-то задать forms? 2. Какие варианты есть решения моей проблемы?  Хотя бы в какую сторону копать. Заранее спасибо :)